# Android MVVM have view respond to async result

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, kotlin

I am working on creating my MVVM template project.
The way MVVM work's is that the View observes changes to the VM and reacts to them. How would i implement that logic in the following example.

View code:

```
fun addPost(): Unit {
    viewModel.addPost(dataSource.text.get(), dataSource.title.get(), { postID: Long ->
        if (postID.equals(0)) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.instance.getContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            (arguments.get(ARG_RunOnPositiveDismiss) as (DMPost) -> Unit)(DMPost(postID, MyOptions.User.GET()!!.UserID, dataSource.title.get(), dataSource.text.get()))
            dismiss()
        }
    })
}
```

ViewModel code:

```
fun addPost(title:String,text:String,onSuccess: (Long) -> Unit): Unit {
        rep.insertPost(DMPost(0, MyOptions.User.GET()!!.UserID, title, text),onSuccess)
}
```

Repository code:

```
fun insertPost(post: DMPost, onSuccess: (Long) -> Unit) {
    if (MyOptions.Online.GET()!!) {
        val client = retrofit.create(APIPost::class.java)
        val insertPost: Call<Long> = client.insertPost(post)
        insertPost.enqueue(object : Callback<Long> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Long>, response: Response<Long>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    onSuccess(response.body()!!)
                } else {
                    onSuccess(0)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Long>, t: Throwable) {
                onSuccess(0)
            }
        })

    } else {
        AsyncTask.execute {
            try {
                onSuccess(daoPost.insertPost(EntityPost(post)))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                onSuccess(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming that i need to have 2 methods in my view, one for showing the error toast and the other for success.the view should observe a value on the VM and on a change on that value, should call one of those 2 methods.

Is my assumption right?
If yes, can someone write the code for that logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewmodel:

```
private MediatorLiveData<YourDataType> mDataObserved;
public LiveData<YourDataType> getDataObserved(){
    return mDataObserved;
}
```

And in your view:

```
viewModel.getDataObserved().observer(this, Observer<YourDataType>{
    // do update view logic in here
});
```

Last, in your repository callback call viewmodel to notify data changed:

```
mDataObserved.postValue(YourDataValue);
```

Comment: Can you give me a rxJava example?